# Knockout selectOptions doesn't update the value

Tags: html, select, knockout.js, model

I have a Model like this

```
    self.userModel = new UserModel({
        profile : userModel.profile(),
    });
```

and in my User Model it looks like that :

```
    self.permissions = ko.observableArray(user && user.permissions ? user.permissions : []);
```

and my options are

```
self.allProfiles = ko.observableArray();
```

and my html :

```
<select class="form-control"
 data-bind="options: allProfiles, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: userModel.profile().id">
</select>
```

The options are there but my problem is that in the View it is not displayed which profile is selected and doesn't update if I select an other option

Comment: There is no any defined dependency (`computed` or subscription) in your models. Changing plain `id` property won't update anything else.

Comment: value should be an observable, in your case it seems that profile is an observable but it isn't

Comment: and show us the views